# Rails Equivalent of SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given the following models:

```
class PeriodBilling < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :appcode
  belongs_to :period
  belongs_to :sla
  belongs_to :unit_type
  belongs_to :dpc_employee
  belongs_to :general_ledger

end

class GeneralLedger < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :appcodes
  has_many :sla_task_details
  belongs_to :expense_category
  has_many :period_billings
  has_many :expected_billings


end
```

How would I find the following SQL equivalent in Rails, to display as a matrix with periods down the left side and general_ledgers across the top, with the sum(pb.current_amt) in the appropriate fields?

```
select pb.pe_number, gl.general_ledger_number, sum(pb.current_amt)
from period_billings pb, general_ledgers gl
where pb.sla_id = 21
and pb.general_ledger_id = gl.id
group by pb.pe_number, gl.general_ledger_number
```

In Active Record terms, this is kinda what I'm trying to find:

```
@sla = Sla.find(params[:id])
@period_billings = PeriodBilling.where("sla_id = ?", @sla.id).group_by(&:general_ledger_id)
@billing_sum = @period_billings.inject(0){|sum,billing| sum+billing.current_amt}
```

So, I want to find all period_billings for the selected sla, grouped by general_ledger_id to get the sum of the period_billing.current_amt for those records.  Then, I want to put the 12 periods down the side to show the summed amount in its appropriate general_ledger column across the top.

Thanks in advance!!!  :)

Comment: it's possible to use specific queries in active record, check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: Yes, but I am a noob and am having trouble with displaying the results in a matrix-like table...

Comment: See if you can digest the question a little bit more.  It's a bit dense for me or most others on SO to sift thru.
Especially the query... try to put it in terms of your active record models and attributes.

Comment: Ok, here's my stab at it.  I tried using Active Record terms before but nobody responded, probably because I'm such a noobie...

Comment: I edited my original post to include my stab at the Active Record equivalent... thanks.

Comment: definitely better, but I'm having trouble figuring out what pb.current_amt is represented by in your models

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild little  stab at what I suggest you do.  Some things are better meant for direct sql, and when that arises, like you're requesting, it's best to just use sql.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute <<-EOF
select pb.pe_number, gl.general_ledger_number, sum(pb.current_amt)
from period_billings pb, general_ledgers gl
where pb.sla_id = 21
and pb.general_ledger_id = gl.id
group by pb.pe_number, gl.general_ledger_number
EOF
```